# How to rotate first element wit flexbox and make it full-height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to implement this graphic with HTML, CSS using flexbox:

[image: Layout-Image to implement with flexbox]

Now, I have trouble with the left part. I don't know how to implement this -90 degrees rotated element. The right part (all elements that are horizontally aligned) is not the problem.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1176px;
  width: 100%!important;
  margin: 0 auto!important;
  float: none!important;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pt {
  padding-top: 3.5rem;
  /* 56px */
}

.pb {
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  /* 48px */
}

.ptms {
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  /* 24px */
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.three-col {
  width: 33.3333334%;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.platform-container,
.platform-card-container {
  display: flex;
}

.platform-card-container .three-col,
.platform-card-container .full-width {
  padding: 0 .75rem;
}

.platform-card-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.platform-card,
.platform-card-first {
  border-radius: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem 0 rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.24);
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.platform-card {
  align-items: center;
}

.platform-card-first {
}

.platform-card-icon {
  padding: .75rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  min-width: 3.5rem;
}

.platform-card-text {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.platform-card-text-title {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  color: #1b1b1b;
}

.platform-card-text-desc {
  color: #007095;
}
```

```html
<div class="container platform-container">
  <div>
    <div class="pt platform-card-container">
      <div class="full-width">
        <a href="">
          <div class="platform-card-first">
            <div class="platform-card-icon">
              <img src="img/icons/axonivy-website-icon-technology-3d-printing-darkblue.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="platform-card-text">
              <h4 class="platform-card-text-title">Open Architecture</h4>
              <div class="platform-card-text-desc">Extend systems as required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="pt platform-card-container">
      <div class="three-col">
        <a href="">
          <div class="platform-card">
            <div class="platform-card-icon">
              <img src="img/icons/axonivy-website-icon-design-ruler-triangle-darkblue.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="platform-card-text">
              <h4 class="platform-card-text-title">User Interface</h4>
              <div class="platform-card-text-desc">Modern front-end technologies</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="three-col">
        <a href="">
          <div class="platform-card">
            <div class="platform-card-icon">
              <img src="img/icons/axonivy-website-icon-mobile-phone-location-darkblue.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="platform-card-text">
              <h4 class="platform-card-text-title">Intelligent Mobility</h4>
              <div class="platform-card-text-desc">Mobile and offline access</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="three-col">
        <a href="">
          <div class="platform-card">
            <div class="platform-card-icon">
              <img src="img/icons/axonivy-website-icon-network-monitor-team-darkblue.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="platform-card-text">
              <h4 class="platform-card-text-title">Social Collaboration</h4>
              <div class="platform-card-text-desc">Efficient teamwork</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ptms platform-card-container">
      <div class="full-width">
        <a href="">
          <div class="platform-card">
            <div class="platform-card-icon">
              <img src="img/icons/axonivy-website-icon-toys-lego-darkblue.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="platform-card-text">
              <h4 class="platform-card-text-title">Low-Code Suppport</h4>
              <div class="platform-card-text-desc">Processes without programming</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ptms platform-card-container">
      <div class="three-col">
        <a href="">
          <div class="platform-card">
            <div class="platform-card-icon">
              <img src="img/icons/axonivy-website-icon-multimedia-shuffle-darkblue.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="platform-card-text">
              <h4 class="platform-card-text-title">Business Rule Engine</h4>
              <div class="platform-card-text-desc">Intelligent decision making</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="three-col">
        <a href="">
          <div class="platform-card">
            <div class="platform-card-icon">
              <img src="img/icons/axonivy-website-icon-programming-module-puzzle-darkblue.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="platform-card-text">
              <h4 class="platform-card-text-title">Integration</h4>
              <div class="platform-card-text-desc">Standard connectors and more</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="three-col">
        <a href="">
          <div class="platform-card">
            <div class="platform-card-icon">
              <img src="img/icons/axonivy-website-icon-transportation-road-sign-darkblue.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="platform-card-text">
              <h4 class="platform-card-text-title">Adaptive Case Management</h4>
              <div class="platform-card-text-desc">Making processes flexible</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ptms platform-card-container">
      <div class="full-width">
        <a href="">
          <div class="platform-card">
            <div class="platform-card-icon">
              <img src="img/icons/axonivy-website-icon-interface-settings-cog-double-darkblue.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="platform-card-text">
              <h4 class="platform-card-text-title">Process Engine</h4>
              <div class="platform-card-text-desc">Powerful process automation</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ptms platform-card-container">
      <div class="full-width">
        <a href="">
          <div class="platform-card">
            <div class="platform-card-icon">
              <img src="img/icons/axonivy-website-icon-work-presentation-projector-screen-darkblue.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="platform-card-text">
              <h4 class="platform-card-text-title">Modern Runtime Platform</h4>
              <div class="platform-card-text-desc">Environment with container support</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Does anyone have a hint on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these styles are what you want:

```css
  text-align: right;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-orientation: mixed;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aycq2v8u/

edit: I noticed that the height still wasn't right. (BTW, display:grid makes this sort of thing easier). here's a revision with that fixed as well. although, this does require either ridiculous looking selectors or changes to the html, which I have done here: https://jsfiddle.net/rxgbo4a9/

changes required:
the card container of the first card (that needs to be full height) needs to be different. since it is on the side and generally different content, I marked it as an aside:

```html
    <aside class="pt platform-card-container">
```

then, with that, using minimal changes to your css we get the desired result:

```css
aside.platform-card-container {
  height:100%
}
aside.platform-card-container a {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%
}
```

note that specifying height instead of using flexbox is not ideal. however, since all your code makes the same mistake, I think you minimize technical debt to keep all the problems of the same type .. ie, keep using height until you are ready to remove it generally.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution works fine.
In the meantime I figured out another possible solution: `transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-50%);position: absolute;top: 50%; left: 0; width: 100%; height: auto;transform-origin: top left;`